# Unrecognized Hibernate Type when using enum in query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, enums

I have an Entity class with a set of enums:

```
@Entity
public class Something {

    public enum Type{
        FIRST_ENUM((short)1),
        SECOND_ENUM((short)2);

        private short id;

        private Type(short id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public short getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    @CollectionTable(name="table_name", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="something_id"))
    @Column(name="type")
    private Set<Type> types;

    ... //other props + getters and setters
}
```

For the enum I made a converter (whole converter package is loaded by @EntityScan annotation) :

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class TypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Type, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Type st) {
        //implementation
    }

    @Override
    public Type convertToEntityAttribute(Integer i) {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Now when I try to use the enum in a query

```
... AND {packagename}.Something$Type.FIRST_ENUM MEMBER OF {someobject}.something.types ...
```

I stumble upon following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Unrecognized Hibernate Type for handling query constant ({package}.Something$Type.FIRST_ENUM); expecting LiteralType implementation or AttributeConverter
```

Does anyone got a clue why I cannot use the enum in my query? It somehow seems the enum is not known to Hibernate. I don't understand why, because the class is loaded when I start my application.